# Parse JSON array in array and use key value

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I get this JSON array via AJAX:

```
{
    "success": 1,
    "message": {
        "ar": {
            "total": 747.4851,
            "list": [{
                "total_statements": 1,
                "total_due": 747.4851,
                "name": "Paul McBilling",
                "connection_id": 154
            }]
        },
        "ap": {
            "total": 0,
            "list": []
        },
        "graphs": {
            "graph": {
                "2016-01": 13,
                "2016-02": 0,
                "2016-03": 0,
                "2016-04": 747.4851,
                "2016-05": 0,
                "2016-06": 0,
                "2016-07": 0,
                "2016-08": 0,
                "2016-09": 0,
                "2016-10": 0,
                "2016-11": 0,
                "2016-12": 0
            }
        },
        "cached": 1
    }
}
```

And the result I would like to get back would look something like this (in the console):

```
2016-01: 13
2016-02: 0
...
```

And I'm trying to log each key and value pair of the inner "graph" array.

I've tried this:

```
$(data.message.graphs.graph).each(function(key, value){
    console.log(key +' and '+ value);
});
```

But what this returns is only once:

```
0 and [object Object]
```

Comment: I think you should use each function one by one for the nested elements to get the 'graph' array in key value pair.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use **[`jQuery.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)** for iterating object

```js
var data = {
  "success": 1,
  "message": {
    "ar": {
      "total": 747.4851,
      "list": [{
        "total_statements": 1,
        "total_due": 747.4851,
        "name": "Paul McBilling",
        "connection_id": 154
      }]
    },
    "ap": {
      "total": 0,
      "list": []
    },
    "graphs": {
      "graph": {
        "2016-01": 13,
        "2016-02": 0,
        "2016-03": 0,
        "2016-04": 747.4851,
        "2016-05": 0,
        "2016-06": 0,
        "2016-07": 0,
        "2016-08": 0,
        "2016-09": 0,
        "2016-10": 0,
        "2016-11": 0,
        "2016-12": 0
      }
    },
    "cached": 1
  }
}

$.each(data.message.graphs.graph,function(key, value) {
  console.log(key + ' and ' + value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Or in pure JavaScript using **[`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)** to get keys array and **[`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)** for iterating it.

```js
var data = {
  "success": 1,
  "message": {
    "ar": {
      "total": 747.4851,
      "list": [{
        "total_statements": 1,
        "total_due": 747.4851,
        "name": "Paul McBilling",
        "connection_id": 154
      }]
    },
    "ap": {
      "total": 0,
      "list": []
    },
    "graphs": {
      "graph": {
        "2016-01": 13,
        "2016-02": 0,
        "2016-03": 0,
        "2016-04": 747.4851,
        "2016-05": 0,
        "2016-06": 0,
        "2016-07": 0,
        "2016-08": 0,
        "2016-09": 0,
        "2016-10": 0,
        "2016-11": 0,
        "2016-12": 0
      }
    },
    "cached": 1
  }
}

Object.keys(data.message.graphs.graph).forEach(function(k) {
  console.log(k + ' and ' + data.message.graphs.graph[k]);
});
```

---

Or even you can use **[`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Iterating_over_own_properties_only)** loop

```js
var data = {
  "success": 1,
  "message": {
    "ar": {
      "total": 747.4851,
      "list": [{
        "total_statements": 1,
        "total_due": 747.4851,
        "name": "Paul McBilling",
        "connection_id": 154
      }]
    },
    "ap": {
      "total": 0,
      "list": []
    },
    "graphs": {
      "graph": {
        "2016-01": 13,
        "2016-02": 0,
        "2016-03": 0,
        "2016-04": 747.4851,
        "2016-05": 0,
        "2016-06": 0,
        "2016-07": 0,
        "2016-08": 0,
        "2016-09": 0,
        "2016-10": 0,
        "2016-11": 0,
        "2016-12": 0
      }
    },
    "cached": 1
  }
}
for (var k in data.message.graphs.graph) {
  if (data.message.graphs.graph.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
    console.log(k + ' and ' + data.message.graphs.graph[k]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Pranav! That was fast :)

Comment: @Frank : glad to help

Answer (score 2):

You can use javascript `for` like following.

```js
var data = {
  "success": 1,
  "message": {
    "ar": {
      "total": 747.4851,
      "list": [{
        "total_statements": 1,
        "total_due": 747.4851,
        "name": "Paul McBilling",
        "connection_id": 154
      }]
    },
    "ap": {
      "total": 0,
      "list": []
    },
    "graphs": {
      "graph": {
        "2016-01": 13,
        "2016-02": 0,
        "2016-03": 0,
        "2016-04": 747.4851,
        "2016-05": 0,
        "2016-06": 0,
        "2016-07": 0,
        "2016-08": 0,
        "2016-09": 0,
        "2016-10": 0,
        "2016-11": 0,
        "2016-12": 0
      }
    },
    "cached": 1
  }
}

var graph = data.message.graphs.graph;
for (var key in graph) {
  console.log(key + ' and ' + graph[key]);
}
```